# Is there a way to extract the date information from the YAML header in Rmarkdown for use in an R chunk?

Tags: r, date, yaml, r-markdown

I am using Rmarkdown to make an electronic lab notebook template. I am using the date entry as my experiment date and I would like to use that same date information for generating file names in the R chunks without having to continually retype the date. Is there a command that can extract this information from the YAML header?

Comment: I've never used it before, but have you seen the `yaml_front_matter()` function from package **rmarkdown**?  It seems like that could work (if you're OK writing in the document name).  I don't know if your dates within one document change through time or something, but you could also manually assign the date as an object in an early set-up chunk and use that for names throughout the rest of the document.  This latter idea would take writing out the date twice instead of once, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *outside* the rmarkdown document, `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter()` should work well for you.

However, if you're talking about *inside* (within a chunk itself), then I think you should look into [Parameterized RMarkdown documents](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html); specifically, include a `params:\n  date: !r Sys.date()`, and elsewhere in your document use `params$date` in R.

For example:

````
---
title: My Document
output: html_document
params:
  date: !r Sys.Date()
---

## Header

Inline, today's date is `r params$date`.

```{r}
cat("In a code chunk, today's date is ", format(params$date, format = "%b %d, %Y"), "\n")
```
````

[image: rendered rmarkdown document]

If you need to specific a specific date other than "today", you can change the value when you render it,

```r
rmarkdown::render('foo.Rmd', params=list(date="2020-01-01"))
```

(Though in this example, `"2020-01-01"` will not be reformatted properly within my example, since `format` won't be getting an actual `Date`-class object. Topic for a different day :-)